# Do Coldfusion Comments add overhead?

Tags: coldfusion

I know this is a fairly entry-level question, but do Coldfusion comments get processed by the server?  Do they add overhead to the application?

I ask because our company has a bad habit introduced by some lazy programmers and bad practices, of just commenting out code that they don't use anymore.  Before we got SVN it sort of made sense since we only had the working copy, but now, even though we have svn people continue to just comment out code.

So does this add overhead?  Are there other issues that this could cause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Comments in ColdFusion source code (CFML) do not add any overhead. All comments in pretty much all programming languages are ignored in compiling.

CFML is compiled directly into Java bytecode. This bytecode can be decompiled to view the java source, but you will never be able to decompile that into the source CFML, and you will never see any comments unless they are added by the decompiler.

The only thing comments do is add to the line count of your original CFML source code.

If you have commented-out code in your files, it will add to the "code smell", and they should be taken out as the original code will always exist in your version control system (just make sure you're actually using version control).

Comment: We are using version control now.  Thank you for your comments, that's what I thought but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there other issues that this could cause?

Yes. It can definitely cause confusion if later programmers come in and look at the code since programmers rarely explain *why* they have commented it out. And at first glance it's not always clear if the code has been commented out and replaced with different code, or if a specific step or action has been removed. At the very least, the commented code should always begin with something like:

```
<!--- Disabled until we can figure out why it sometimes 
      deletes all tables from the database

<cfset ...
--->
```

or

```
<!--- Removed (temporarily?) because Bob said so (see Ticket #AZ345

<cfset ...
--->
```

I think the best time to comment out code is when there is a functionality that you plan to have implemented at some point but are momentarily keeping disabled. For example, you plan at some point to send out SMS-based confirmation messages, but don't have the gateway set up yet. You can write the code, comment it out, and then un-comment it at a later point (you could create a separate branch for this, but I think that's sort of overkill). Similarly, there are some functions that are temporarily enabled or disabled (for example, something that re-appears every holiday season) where it makes sense to keep the code in an accessible place.

Comment: I've worked at a company where we would comment out code (with an appropriate explanation) if there was a particular approach we'd tried that ended up causing complications in other parts of the application, so that a later developer wouldn't try the same change with the same results. Certainly this can be documented elsewhere (version control, project documentation), but as you put it, the concern was accessibility; ensuring that something wouldn't be re-broken just because someone didn't check all available documentation first.